# sed: How to extract only first occurance of value

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have file `settings.inc.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
define('_DB_SERVER_', 'mariadb');
define('_DB_NAME_', 'organic');
define('_DB_USER_', 'prestashop');
define('_DB_PASSWD_', 'prestashop');
```

I want to extract these values to `bash`, so I managed to create the following command:

```
sed -rn 's/^.*_DB_NAME_'\'', '\''(\w+)'\''\);/\1/p' settings.inc.php
```

This will return `organic`, just as it should, but I would like to improve it further. Let's say we would have this kind of file:

```
<?php
define('_DB_SERVER_', 'mariadb');
define('_DB_NAME_', 'organic1');
define('_DB_NAME_', 'organic2');
define('_DB_USER_', 'prestashop');
define('_DB_PASSWD_', 'prestashop');
```

Using above command on this file we would get:

```
organic1
organic2
```

The thing is: I want for this command to always return only one value, so let's say the first one. Can I achieve that without piping result into second command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert your substitute command followed by print to a command block operating only on lines addressed by pattern (containing) `_DB_NAME_`, you can quit after the first match/print:

```
$ sed -rn "/_DB_NAME_/ { s/.*'(\w+)'\);$/\1/p;q }" settings.inc.php
organic1
```

Note the `q` command after `p`.

Also, your `sed` script can be simplified by using outer double quotes and anchoring on the end.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep you could do it:

```
grep -m1 -Po "_DB_NAME_', '\K[^']+" settings.inc.php
```

The grep arguments are:

- `-m 1`: stops the search after 1 match
- `-P`: turns on Perl style regex (so we can use `\K` here)
- `-o`: only print the part of the line that matches the pattern

The `\K` part of the pattern says not to include everything up to that point as part of the match, we then have the rest of the pattern finding everything that's not a `'`.

If you wanted to stick with `sed` you could find the `_DB_NAME_` line, then quit after you found it:

```
 sed -rn '/_DB_NAME/ {s/^.*_DB_NAME_'\'', '\''(\w+)'\''\);/\1/;p;q}' settings.inc.php
```

which matches `_DB_NAME_` then goes into the block that does your `s`ubstitution, `p`rints the line, then `q`uits

Answer (score 2):

Can also use `awk`

```
$ awk -F "'" '$2=="_DB_NAME_"{print $4; exit}' settings.inc.php 
organic1
```

- `-F "'"` use single quotes as input field separator
- `$2=="_DB_NAME_"` check if second field is `_DB_NAME_`
- `print $4` if condition satisfies, print 4th field
- `exit` as only first match is needed

Answer (score 1):

Pipe your `sed` command to `head` and select the first row as show below:

```
sed -rn 's/^.*_DB_NAME_'\'', '\''(\w+)'\''\);/\1/p' settings.inc.php | head -1
```